# How to cut sphere with sphere? Topology problem

Tags: mesh, modifiers, topology

Basically it is a letter N. Tried many ways with no luck or lack...of knowledge.. :)  trying to make my own logo to 3d. Using boolean and rotating spheres, but topology is big problem.

[image]

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you familiar with manual retopoligize?

Comment: Yes, but somehow, it never looks how it should be. Apparently I'm not too good at manual retopologizing...I was kinda hoping there is some automatic way

Comment: If nobody anwser this I'll try to make it tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still trying...If somehow I manage to make it, I will post it here...

Comment: @RobertNol Try to rotate the sphere 45 degrees and then add boolean.

Comment: @RobertNol Bad news, I didn't found any auto method for this shape. I've tried quick retopo: http://imgur.com/a/s6d73. I'ts ugly with bad edge loop flow but it was just a test. You'll need to reptopologize only 1/4 of the mesh, then mirror it and then copy, rotate and manualy join.

Comment: @Denis I tried many rotations, tried even with ico sphere, and than with combination of ico and uv sphere...

Comment: @LukeD You are right, I will need to do it manualy. Thanks a lot  for tip 1/4, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Feel free to ask if you need some more tips. To retopo I'm using only F2 addon and standard extrude/fill techniques. With face snapping of course.

Comment: Do the edges need to be rounded or could they be sharp?

Comment: Sorry for late answer, I did it...manualy...It was hard, but I did it...Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to avoid much work here with simple [inset](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/duplicating/inset.html). It won't provide great topology straight away, it will add loopcut all over the corners where sharpening is needed in order to add Subsurf.

[image: scr-retopoed]

When you have a letter just after the Boolean chances are it looks something like tris, lack of continous loops etc. Select the part with indentations (the one you'd like to sharpen out):

[image: scr-selection-for-inset]

Invert the selection (most likely face selection will be the most comfortable). It's also possible to use *Outset* option by pressing <kbd>O</kbd> while Inset is active; then insetting will happen outwards and this step should be skipped:

[image: scr-inverted-selection]

Then inset with <kbd>I</kbd>. There will be some areas where inset will create self-intersecting geometry, some cleaning work will be needed. However it might not be necessary to do it for all the letter (although it all depends on the final result as always):

[image: scr-insetted]

Answer (score -1):

I think your mesh is not fine enough to start with. Add a subdivision surface modifier and repeat the bool operation and you will get a smooth result.

Comment: Didn't work...Edges still not looking right. Looking better but not how it should be.

Comment: How many subdivision levels did you add? Try to add three or four levels to each of the bool objects, hit "apply" on the modifiers (not necessary, I think, but just to be on the safe side) and then do the bool operation. That should give you plenty of faces to get a smooth result. Subsurf info: https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/subsurf.html